# Namespacing inside tags with Python lxml's SubElement

Tags: python, lxml

I'm using Python and the lxml library to produce an XML file that I want to look like this:

```
<item>
  <a:text>hello</a:text>
</item>
```

However, I can't manage to produce this, I've tried the following code:

```
import lxml.etree as etree
item = etree.Element('item')
el = etree.SubElement(item, 'text', nsmap={'a': 'http://example.com/')
```

But then I end up with:

```
<item>
  <text xmlns="http://example.com/">hello</text>
</item>
```

I also tried this after some inspiration from the lxml namespaces documentation (http://lxml.de/tutorial.html#namespaces):

```
import lxml.etree as etree
item = etree.Element('item')
el = etree.SubElement(item, '{a}text')
```

But that gives me:

```
<item>
  <ns1:text xmlns:ns1="a">hello</text>
</item>
```

Is there any way to get the XML format I need with lxml ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The first thing to note is that this...

```
<item>
  <a:text>hello</a:text>
</item>
```

...is not valid XML.  `a:` is a namespace *prefix*, but somewhere you have to map it to an actual namespace, as in:

```
<item xmlns:a="http://example.com/">
  <a:text>hello</a:text>
</item>
```

As you read in the lxml documentation, you can use the `{namespace}element` syntax to specify a namespace...but this uses an actual namespace, *not* a namespace prefix (which is why your second example did not work as expected).

You can get what I think you want like this:

```
>>> from lxml import etree
>>> item = etree.Element('item', nsmap={'a': 'http://example.com/'})
>>> e1 = etree.SubElement(item, '{http://example.com/}text')
```

Which gives you:

```
>>> print etree.tostring(item, pretty_print=True)
<item xmlns:a="http://example.com/">
  <a:text/>
</item>
```

It's also worth noting that from the perspective of XML, the above is *exactly* equivalent to:

```
<item>
  <text xmlns="http://example.com/">hello</text>
</item>
```